# How to disable input box angular 2 material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Please Read my **Description** First

HTML File

```html
<div class="row col-md-2">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="nameInput col-md-2">
      <mat-label>One</mat-label>
      <input
      matInput
      [(ngModel)]="One"
      (ngModelChange)="onChangeDisable()"
      />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-2">
   <mat-form-field
      appearance="outline"
      class="nameInput col-md-2"
      >
      <mat-label>Two</mat-label>
      <input
      matInput
      [(ngModel)]="Two"
      (ngModelChange)="onChangeDisable()"
      [disabled]="twoDisabled"
      />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';



/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
One:any;
Two:any;
twoDisabled=true;


    onChangeDisable() {
        if (this.One != null) {
            this.twoDisabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are Two input box Named "One" & "Two" , On first time both input box must be enabled but when i enter any value into First Input box then second input box must get disabled , and when i clear the fileds from first input then second input box will get enable same thing must be done with second input box HOW?

My StackBlitz Link --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-input12345677709-gfj1-gxqswz-u1tbuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an solution for you.

Just change method like this.

```
 onChangeDisable() {
       if(this.One!=null && this.One!=''){
         this.twoDisabled=true;
       }else{
         this.twoDisabled=false;
       }
    }
```

I have checked this code with your stackblitz.It's working.

Update:-

Here is an example for both checking your condition,

Html:-

```
  <input
      matInput
      [(ngModel)]="One"
      (ngModelChange)="onChangeDisable()"
      [disabled]="oneDisabled"
      />
```

Tyepescript

```
oneDisabled=false;
 onChangeDisable(isSecond) {
      if(!isSecond){
        if(this.One!=null && this.One!=''){
         this.twoDisabled=true;
       }else{
         this.twoDisabled=false;
       }
      }else{
         if(this.Two!=null && this.Two!=''){
         this.oneDisabled=true;
       }else{
         this.oneDisabled=false;
       }
      }

    }
```

here is an stackblitz for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-input12345677709-gfj1-gxqswz-u1tbuk-6w3qjh

Comment: Many answers but you post the answer what actually i want Thank you sir!

Comment: Glad to help you.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both inputs are enabled by setting `twoDisabled = false` at first. And when user add value in the first input then change `twoDisabled = true`.

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  One: any;
  Two: any;
  twoDisabled = false;


  onChangeDisable() {
    if (!this.One) {
      this.twoDisabled = false;
    }
    else {
      this.twoDisabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can consider the same logic for the second input, but it also depends on different cases. Like: both has values, only second input has value...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below :

```
    export class TableBasicExample {
      One: any;
      Two: any;
      twoDisabled = false;

      onChangeDisable() {
        if (this.One) {
          this.twoDisabled = true;
        } else {
          this.twoDisabled = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({...})
export class TableBasicExample {
  one: any;
  two: any;
  currentlyDisabled: string;

  onChangeDisable() {
    if(this.one) {
      this.currentlyDisabled = 'two';
    } else if (this.two) {
      this.currentlyDisabled = 'one';
    } else {
      this.currentlyDisabled = '';
    }
  }

}
```

And in the Template:

```
<div class="row col-md-2">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="nameInput col-md-2">
      <mat-label>One</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        [(ngModel)]="one"
        (change)="onChangeDisable()"
        [disabled]="currentlyDisabled === 'one'"
      />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-2">
   <mat-form-field
      appearance="outline"
      class="nameInput col-md-2"
      >
      <mat-label>Two</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        [(ngModel)]="two"
        (change)="onChangeDisable()"
        [disabled]="currentlyDisabled === 'two'"
      />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-input-disable-based-on-other-input?file=app/table-basic-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you sir, you code is working as i want but input box get disabled when i clicked on input boxes